# Using distinct in comma seperated list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

Can someone Explain why i get only last row ?

where as when i remove **`DISTINCT`** i can able to achieve full rows.

```
DECLARE @liststr VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
;WITH COMMA (name)
AS
(
        SELECT 'a' 
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'b'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'd'
)
SELECT DISTINCT @liststr = @liststr+',' + name FROM comma
SELECT @liststr as Result
```

Comment: It would help if you edit the question to include a table of expected output and actual output.

Comment: And please fix the misplaced statement terminator (`;`) and add all the missing ones.

Comment: Why the f was `DISTINCT` added there in the first place? What was it supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original, unedited question you use UNION instead of UNION ALL in your CTE so the DISTINCT is unnecessary. Consider the following query:

```
DECLARE @liststr VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
WITH COMMA (name)
AS
(
        SELECT 'a' 
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'b'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'd'
)
SELECT @liststr = @liststr+',' + name FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM comma) AS comma;
SELECT @liststr as Result;
```

Here is the query plan for the above:

[image: query plan 1]

The sort occurs before the string concatenation, which is what you want. The result is ",a,b,d".

Now consider this query:

```
DECLARE @liststr VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
WITH COMMA (name)
AS
(
        SELECT 'a' 
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'b'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'a'
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'd'
)
SELECT DISTINCT @liststr = @liststr+',' + name FROM comma;
SELECT @liststr as Result;
```

Here is the query plan for the above:

[image]

The sort occurs after the string concatenation, which is not what you want. The result is ",d".

I don't recommend using either query. I don't know what we are seeing here is defined behavior or if you'll consistently get the result that you want from the first query. It's possible that you'll end up with a query that works now but is broken by a future update of SQL Server. If it's important for you to get consistent results for this query you may want to consider a different method of string concatenation.

Comment: Changed my question.

Comment: Please don't (change the question) after others have answered. It might make their answers invalid.

Comment: UNION ALL does not eliminate duplicate rows.

Comment: The DISTINCT forces SQL to first sort and then remove duplicates.  When a duplicate row is removed, how do you know what the state of @liststr is?

Comment: @MguerraTorres In the unedited question he used UNION instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: @Queue Mann I am not advocating this as a solution. I tried to make that clear in the last paragraph. I was just providing a workaround and a partial explanation to the behavior that he was seeing.

Comment: @JoeObbish kudos on the attempt to help.  Unfortunately if the OP changes the original question we get nowhere.

Comment: yep this behaviour is not guaranteed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136